# Removing Popular Repositories Section- Github

Tags: github

Having some trouble with GitHub to remove the **Popular repositories** section tried to search for a fix and saw this [help page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile) but when I click **Customise your pins** the options to show repositories doesnt exist

Is this setting deprecated?
Is it even possible to remove the **Popular repositories** section?

Answer (score 8):

Just for anyone that may want a workaround:

On the right of the Popular Respositories there is a `View As: Public`. You can change this to be `View As: Member` and they go away.

`https://github.com/<your organization>/?view_as=member`

Bookmark that page instead!

Comment: Not what I was searching for but still good information, thx!

Comment: THANK YOU! I swear that section is only there because the data science team working on the recommendation backend is paid way too much.

Answer (score 2):

Still not possible to remove the section, but according to the [official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#popular-repositories) by pinning one or more (up to six) public repositories the Popular section will be renamed Pinned.

Perhaps with more upvotes on this [discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/15310) the remove/disable option will be made available.